# Fullcalendar.io dynamic data loading for currently visible period

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a large event dataset so I'd like to find a way to load data for the period (start & end date range) currently visible calendar.

I tried the following hoping that "prev" somehow accepts callback, but it doesn't work.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 prev: function() {
    console.log('prev button pressed. data for the current date range will be fetched.');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are trying to load more events that are currently shown on screen, so that they are cached and prev/next switching works faster.

If so, then I'm using events: as a function. I'm expanding the data window by two months each side and load 4 months data.

```
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar() {
    ...
    , events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        start.subtract(2, 'months');
        end.add(2, 'months');
        //ajax call that fetches data for 4 months using start and end as parameters
}
```